# Can the names of parameters in function definition be same as the name of arguments passed to it in the function call in C++?

Tags: c++, function, c++14

Suppose we have a function as given below:

```
int add(int num1, int num2) { 
    num1 += num2;
    return num1;
}
```

Now, I call the above function by passing the arguments having the same name as the parameters in the add function.

```
int num1 = 10;
int num2 = 10;

int result = add(num1, num2)
```

Is it correct to do so? The code compiles correctly But I am not sure whether I am doing the correct thing or not?

Comment: The function doesn't care what the names of the arguments are, or even if they have names (i.e. numerical expressions); that's part of the reason for *having* parameters.

Comment: Generally, when a code compiles and gives correct results...

Comment: its a rather frequent beginner mistake to assume that there would be some magic link between same named parameters and arguments, hence my suggestion is to not name them the same, though thats only a question of style

Comment: Off-topic, but why complicate things by not writing `return num1 + num2;`?

Comment: The caller's *arguments* passed to the function's *parameters* do not have to have the same names.  They don't even have to be variables, you can call `int result = add(10, 5+5);`.  (If the *parameters* are **references**, then that's a slightly different situation.)

Comment: What you're passing to the function is not the names or the variables, but the values of the variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the names of the variables you pass in a function call can be the same as the names of the parameters in the function definition. The scope of the function parameters begins and ends in the function block, so the compiler can keep the two (or more) variables defined at different scopes separate, even when they have the same name.

You can call your function by passing variables with the same name (`add(num1, num2)`), different names (`add(x, y)`), or no names at all (`add(3, 4)`).

See the **Function parameter scope** section in the [C++ Scope](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/scope) reference.